# Cubic interpolation python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I have a python assignment related to image processing.
One of the functions I need to implement is called `compute_cubic_interpolation_coefficients(coefficient[][][])`, and the description of it is:

> This function computes the 4x4 = 16 cubic coefficients for each
>   quarter of a pixel using a cubic approximation of a Gaussian function.

I must admit I don't fully understand how that should be calculated, I guess (just guess) that the first two dimensions of the array represents the 2D pixels map, while the 3rd dimension array should contain 16 values per each pixels (or something like that).

Note: this is my first assignment for this course so it would be really valuable if anyone may help me to understand how to implement that correctly.

Comment: BTW if anyone is willing to give me just a clue for what I should do that would be awesome as well. Thanks!

Comment: The [Bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) should help you to understand the [Bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). [Here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Python) a bilinear interpolation in Python.